# How to replace an re match with a transformation of that match?

Tags: python, regex

For example, I have a string:

```
The struct-of-application and struct-of-world
```

With `re.sub`, it will replace the matched with a predefined string.  How can I replace the match with a transformation of the matched content?  To get, for example:

```
The [application_of_struct](http://application_of_struct) and [world-of-struct](http://world-of-struct)
```

If I write a simple regex `((\w+-)+\w+)` and try to use `re.sub`, it seems I can't use what I matched as part of the replacement, let alone edit the matched content:

```
In [10]: p.sub('struct','The struct-of-application and struct-of-world')
Out[10]: 'The struct and struct'
```

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase I will add the result of re.sub soon

Comment: Use more than one line of code?

Comment: @wwii how ?  searched and replaced ?

Comment: Read the [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)...  You need to make use of the **capturing group** (which you've already created, intentionally or otherwise.  They're described in the [Grouping](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping) section:  "Groups indicated with `(`, `)` also capture the starting and ending index of the text that they match; this can be retrieved by passing an argument to `group()`, `start()`, `end()`, and `span()`. [...]".

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase of cause I know something about `group` . But the group does solve the problem of  `find matched and replace with matched`.

Comment: Backreferences (as used in the answer Nehal J Wani has already provided) are introduced in the "Grouping" section I suggested above.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase sorry about that. but it required more to do , have updated the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a [function for the replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
s = 'The struct-of-application and struct-of-world'
p = re.compile('((\w+-)+\w+)')
def replace(match):
    return 'http://{}'.format(match.group())
    #for python 3.6+ ... 
    #return f'http://{match.group()}'

>>> p.sub(replace, s)

'The http://struct-of-application and http://struct-of-world'
>>>
```

Comment: That's what i need. Thank for the sharing :)

Comment: Very neat! I have made so many really messy work arounds this problem before! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r"((\w+-)+\w+)")
>>> p.sub('[\\1](http://\\1)','The struct-of-application and struct-of-world')
'The [struct-of-application](http://struct-of-application) and [struct-of-world](http://struct-of-world)'
```

Comment: I wonder if i can edit the matched content and use it to replace ?