# How to replace several URLs in text with python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have XML with many weblinks which are URL encoded. I can't to use this XML before I decode all weblinks in it.

I have written such code in python:

```
import re
from urllib.parse import unquote
from transliterate import translit, get_available_language_codes

myString = """&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td style="text-align: center;"&gt;&lt;a href="https://somewebsite.com/s1600/%25D0%2593%25D0%259E%25D0%25A0%25D0%259E%25D0%25A1%25D0%259A%25D0%259E%25D0%259F%2B%25D0%2592%25D0%25A0%%25D0%2590.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"&gt;&lt;img border="0" data-original-height="470" data-original-width="820" height="366" src="https://somewebsite.com/AAAAAAAAzAM/nhpZKVGvEWAn-UNufwn1npX7aTucSWFUwCLcBGAs/s640/%25D0%2593%25D0%259E%25D0%25A0%25D0%259E%25D0%25A1%25D0%259A%25D0%22%25D0%2598.%2B%25D0%25A1%25D0%2590%25D0%259C%25D0%25AB%25D0%2595%90.jpg" width="640" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td class="tr-caption" style="text-align: center;"&gt;;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a name='more'&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;div align="center"&gt;&lt;script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/jshttps://somewebsite.com/-_7TnRcBGpRY/%2597%25D0%259D%25D0%2590%25D0%259A%25D0%25A3%2B%25D0%2597%25D0%259E%25D0%2594%25D0%2598%25D0%2590%25D0%259A%25D0%2590.jpg"""
b = re.findall("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", myString)
c = unquote(unquote(b))
d = translit(c, 'ru', reversed=True)
```

Now I can: 
1. Decode any of link separately 
2. Create an array of decoded links

But I have no ideas how can I replace in myString all encoded links (default one) by those which where decoded by me.

I have found a way to receive all decoded links but I don't really know how to replace old ones in myString by new ones.

Comment: Do you need a regex here? `html.unescape(myString)` should get you most of the way...

Comment: Thank you for a comment. It doesn't give proper links unfortunately.

Comment: Nope - there's still more work to be done but I'm guessing that's getting closer to what you're after?

Comment: If you have a look at the bs4 docs, you can see you can also replace elements in a soupified string... I'm not clear on exactly what operations you want to perform or which attributes to replace but hopefully you've got a decent enough starting point.

Comment: You are looking for a callback method passed as the replacement argument to `re.sub`. And that makes it a dupe of [Passing a function to re.sub in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737863/passing-a-function-to-re-sub-in-python). Here is [anoter helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009967/how-to-replace-an-re-match-with-a-transformation-of-that-match). `re.sub(r'https?://\S+', your_escaping_method, text)`

Comment: Indeed: "anoter helpful post" is very close for that I have been looking for. Thank you for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `html.unescape` to get your string more readily parseable, then use BeautifulSoup4 (pip install bs4) to find loop over all tags and do whatever's needed to get the src/href/whatever you specify attributes into shape, then convert the soup object back to a string.

```
from html import unescape
from urllib.parse import unquote
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

myString = """&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td style="text-align: center;"&gt;&lt;a href="https://somewebsite.com/s1600/%25D0%2593%25D0%259E%25D0%25A0%25D0%259E%25D0%25A1%25D0%259A%25D0%259E%25D0%259F%2B%25D0%2592%25D0%25A0%%25D0%2590.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"&gt;&lt;img border="0" data-original-height="470" data-original-width="820" height="366" src="https://somewebsite.com/AAAAAAAAzAM/nhpZKVGvEWAn-UNufwn1npX7aTucSWFUwCLcBGAs/s640/%25D0%2593%25D0%259E%25D0%25A0%25D0%259E%25D0%25A1%25D0%259A%25D0%22%25D0%2598.%2B%25D0%25A1%25D0%2590%25D0%259C%25D0%25AB%25D0%2595%90.jpg" width="640" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td class="tr-caption" style="text-align: center;"&gt;;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a name='more'&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;div align="center"&gt;&lt;script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/jshttps://somewebsite.com/-_7TnRcBGpRY/%2597%25D0%259D%25D0%2590%25D0%259A%25D0%25A3%2B%25D0%2597%25D0%259E%25D0%2594%25D0%2598%25D0%2590%25D0%259A%25D0%2590.jpg"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(unescape(myString), 'html.parser')
# loop over all elements and update anything src/href attributes
for tag in soup.find_all():
    for attr in tag.attrs.keys() & {'src', 'href'}:
        # do whatever else with tag[attr] here
        tag[attr] = unquote(unquote(tag[attr]))

output = str(soup)
```

Gives you:

```
'&gt;<tr><td style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://somewebsite.com/s1600/ГОРОСКОП+ВР%А.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"><img border="0" data-original-height="470" data-original-width="820" height="366" src=\'https://somewebsite.com/AAAAAAAAzAM/nhpZKVGvEWAn-UNufwn1npX7aTucSWFUwCLcBGAs/s640/ГОРОСК�"И.+САМЫЕ�.jpg\' width="640"/></a></td></tr><tr><td class="tr-caption" style="text-align: center;">;<br/><a name="more"></a><br/><br/><div align="center">&lt;script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/jshttps://somewebsite.com/-_7TnRcBGpRY/%2597%25D0%259D%25D0%2590%25D0%259A%25D0%25A3%2B%25D0%2597%25D0%259E%25D0%2594%25D0%2598%25D0%2590%25D0%259A%25D0%2590.jpg</div></td></tr>'
```

Of course - your mileage will vary with how much the parser can make sense of the input to start with.

Comment: Thank you for a code but I have already created array of decoded weblinks. The problem lays in area that I don't know how to replace old links in myString with a new ones.

Comment: Okay - two ticks