# Re replacement with transformation

Tags: python, regex

I have a string where all unicode characters have been replaced by their integer values and enclosed in brackets. For example, é has been replaced with [233]. I want to convert those integers back to unicode characters (and get rid of the brackets, obviously). I thought the easiest way would be to use a simple regex replacement (using the `re` library), but I'm getting an error.

Here's a simple example that doesn't work:

```
s = 'Som[233] string'
re.sub(r'\[(\d+)\]', chr(int(r'\1')), s)
```

This returns the error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\\1'

Note that I get the same thing using the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39010137/4325492) related question.

The error suggests that the string `\\1` is being passed to `int()` instead of the actual capture group.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

> If repl is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping
>   occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object
>   argument, and returns the replacement string.

So then I tried this, following the example in the documentation:

```
def replace(match):
    return chr(int(match.group(0)))
re.sub(r'\[(\d+)\]', replace, s)
```

But that returns a similar error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[233]'

What am I missing here? Why is list being passed to the function instead of the capture group?

Answer (score 0):

The function above *does* work as expected. The brackets in the second warning are not because a list is being return, but because capture group 0 includes the *entire* group and not just the digits:

```
re.search(r'\[(\d+)\]', s).group(0)
# '[233]'
re.search(r'\[(\d+)\]', s).group(1)
# '233'
```

So the solution is just to change which group is being used in the function:

```
def replace(match):
    return chr(int(match.group(1)))
```